# Heat and Sugar Syrup Consistency

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions, food-chemistry, carbohydrates

I make my own sugar syrups and have been observing how heating the syrup to different degrees results in syrups of radically different consistencies, I wonder why. Heating up syrups (4:3 Sugar:Water) to greater temperatures causes the resulting syrup to be relatively viscous while low temperatures yield relatively thin syrups. I do really think that my observations are valid and thought this'd be the right place to get the answers. I want to know of the chemical and physical processes involved in solutions of sugar and why their peak temperatures affect their consistencies.

Comment: You're not the first one who notices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramelization

Comment: @Karl Um. I didn't mean it to be that. Just that my searches didn't put out anything good enough wrt my "why"s. And this link- I'm afraid it's not what I was looking for.  My question concerns the consistencies, not the process of caramelization, which is something I do possess the knowledge of.

Comment: Question: Since you didn't specify the temperatures you're dealing with, and  hence we don't know if this is due to caramelization as @Karl points out... could you mention if the syrup regains it's original consistency when cooled back to room temperature? If not, I suspect the increased viscosity could be either due to caramelization (*Kudos to Karl*) or perhaps it was simply the *evaporation* of large amounts of water (if the solution wasn't *boiling*) which would thereby increase the concentration, and hence the viscosity, of the syrup. Good question though, and welcome to Chemistry.SE! ;)

Comment: @paracetamol I'm dealing with the critical caramelization temperatures in most cases, and my sugar does indeed get caramelized. So the caramelized sugars are more viscous, then, I guess? Is it the polymers, carmelen and caramelin, that make the caramelized products denser?